Adding a scroll eventlistener when a sibling component is using overscroll-y-auto in Next.js 14
I am making something in Next.js 14.  I have an accordion component, that will stretch out along the y axis of the page as it is opened, in a page.  I am using overflow-y-scroll in the main container element of the page so that the page background covers the entire y distance of the page as the accordion expands.  If I don't use overflow-y-scroll then I have this unwanted white space at the bottom of the page.
In my navbar, which is currently in my main layout, I want to add a scroll event listener.  when a page initiall loads the navbar is see through, but as the user scrolls down the accordion section i want it to have a solid background so that i don't have navbar link text on top of accordion component text.
So here is my problem.  While overflow-y-scroll is acting on the page, the scroll event listener is not working.  A console.log of the window.scrollY is not showing anything, and the useState boolean variable i have set up to detect a change in scrollY is not changing to true when I scroll.  But if I remove overflow-y-scroll, then my navbar effect works, I am getting a console log of scrollY and I have this unwanted white space at the end of my page.
How can I get both of the things I want at the same time?  Any help would be appreciated.  If I can't figure this out I am going to have to change my state variable with an onClick on my accordion component...  But using a scroll event would be better.
I tried removing the overflow-y-scroll.  I tried using document.querySelector('main').addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll), but that didn't work.
I am using the window object right now:
const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
      const scrollThreshold = 110;
      console.log(window.scrollY);
      setIsScrolled(scrollPosition >= scrollThreshold);
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  });

this works when I remove overflow-y-scroll from the page that my accordion component is imported in.
I added true, after both callbacks in the addEventListener, and removeEventListener, and now my console log of window.scrollY is working but it only shows 0.
